# Evaluate Overlapping Date Ranges for MULTIPLE Rows

Tags: vb.net

I have a table that populates with an ID,Closed and Reopen Date. If I edit the date range for a particular ID. I need a way to check for overlapping dates across ALL date ranges in the table against  the desired ID I changed. I have tried this below but am only evaluating on a row by row basis. Given the example below how could I get for example ID 2 to evaluate across all 6 rows if i  changed closed to 9/17/2017?

[image]

```
    Dim b As String = ddlB.SelectedValue
    Dim l As String = ddlL.SelectedValue

    Dim evaluatedID As Integer = ID.Value

    Dim evaluatedClosedDate As Date = rdpCloseDate.SelectedDate

    Using sta As New dsdMyDataset.MyTableAdapter
        sta.Connection = My.DataHandler.MyDBConnection
        Dim tbl As New dsdMyDataset.MyDataTable
        sta.Fill(tbl, b, l)
        For Each row In tbl
            If evaluatedID < row.ID And evaluatedClosedDate < row.ReopenedDate Then
                Return False
            ElseIf evaluatedID = row.ID And evaluatedClosedDate < row.ReopenedDate Then
                Return False
            ElseIf evaluatedID > row.ID And evaluatedClosedDate > row.ReopenedDate Then
                Return False
            ElseIf evaluatedID = Nothing OrElse evaluatedClosedDate = Nothing OrElse row.ReopenedDate = Nothing Then
                Return False
            Else
                Return True
            End If
        Next
    End Using
```

Comment: Sort them, then you only need to check adjacent rows?

Comment: ps; it's  bit odd that you set the connection on a TableAdapter; in usual use cases you eave them alone to get their own connection - why are you giving it?

Comment: @CaiusJard you are correct I don't need the connection. This has been removed. Could you please elaborate on the sort with an example? Not sure how I can evaluate multiple rows using it. Thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to determine if any row is overlapped by any other row, or do you specifically need to know which rows overlap a particular row? What will you do when you finish your process? What is the output of the logic?

Comment: Is "closed" the "from" date and "reopen" the "to" date? I ask because linguistically I'd assume the other way round..

Comment: evaluatedClosedDate will be edited for one of my IDs. Upon Save this function mentioned above is called, it will take the ID of the evaluatedClosedDate being edited and then needs to compare against any of the date ranges derived from my table. So in this instance. if I change ID 2 It cannot overlap with any of the date ranges close-reopen for all 6 rows.  Yes closed is from and reopen is to